# Matlab vectorization of for loops to manipulate pixels in a RGB image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, for-loop, vectorization, logical-operators

I am still learning about matlab and I am trying to understand vectorization. I think the root of my issue is that I don't understand how to reference the different matrices and such. I am hoping an answer to this question will help me understand.

```
FI = imread(ForegroundImageName);
BI = imread(BackgroundImageName);
refRows =size(FI,1);
refCols =size(FI,2);
refChan =size(FI,3);
CommonRGB = mode(mode(FI));
BI = imresize(BI, [refRows refCols]);
swappedPixels = 0;

for row=1:refRows
    for col=1:refCols
        if(FI(row,col,:)==CommonRGB)
            FI(row,col,:)=BI(row,col,:);
            swappedPixels = swappedPixels + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Background of this question is that I am replacing a foreground pixel with a background pixel if the foreground pixel matches the most common color. CommonRGB is a 1x1x3 matrix as `mode(mode(FI))` spits its out. The images are 3D color RGB images. I chose this as a simple example of my issue. This for loop performs what I want it to do and seems to work. Its just that it takes a long time to run through the for loop. I perform `mode(mode(FI))` is fractions of the time it takes to run the above for loop and I tried to implement `mode(mode(FI))` myself and it gets pretty complicated in comparison to the pixel swapping above. I had similar issues when creating a histogram. I hope you can help me learn more about matlab and expand my programming knowledge into this language. I know it makes it easier if I say that I want to perform these operations on the entire matrix so if we vectorize it I would assume we don't need the `refRows`, `refCols`, and `refChan` variables in this instance.

[image: Foreground]
[image: Background]
[image: Background Replaced]

One of my failed attempts

```
if(FI(:,:,:)==CommonRGB)
    FI(:,:,:)=BI(:,:,:);
    swappedPixels = swappedPixels + 1;
end
```

From the answers so far, they have shown methods to vectorize the logic. The takeaway that I get is that ANY OTHER METHOD that doesn't involve long for loops will be incredibly faster than using large for loops like I have done. Even if it means creating extra arrays and doing extra processes like creating a mask array and running over the picture many times. The root of the problem from what I can tell and guess is that the JIT Just In Time compiler of matlab has to reparse the command on every iteration of the for loop. This parsing and dealing with the for loop is the real root of the speed problem. If matlab could "see" the for loop and plan ahead then it would run faster. Thus, there is nothing I can do to the original code where I would just replace row and col with something else and remove the two for loops. I would have to devise other methods that do not use the big for loops. Only then will it run at a reasonable speed. This tells me that matlab is a true scripting language on the front end since running scripts with for loops similarly suffer detrimental performance degradation. Therefore, I am unsure how to mark this question as answered, not answered, or vote up other answers. Since if I change the logic inside the for loops then I would have to change how I implement the speed up.

SO, unless someone can show me how to just replace the variables row and col inside the for loop with something else like `1:refRows`, use parfor, use something easy that only changes the code inside the for loop and removes the for loops, or can just write an answer verifying the paragraph above, then I am not sure what to do at this point.

As @Divakar said "You are right that there isn't a clear-cut vectorization technique here to just plugin the loop parameters and have a vectorized solution out of it. If you had a single loop instead of the this two nested loops situation, you could have gotten a more direct plug-n-play vectorized solution using logical indexing. But yes, vectorization can't be generalized in most cases and need to dealt with as case-per-case basis. Good luck with the vectorizing explorations! –  Divakar"

That being said, I would like to help other people by showing them what I did to apply what I learned from this question. It seemed that I already had the algorithm figured out I think, although I am still unsure if my phase 3 selection of common hue using the light threshold is even working. I don't see it select a different hue when the light threshold goes up. I just see phase 3 consistently select a different hue than phase 2. I didn't realize this until today. Not important to the question itself, but below is important to the question because I mention the for loop method and then implement a vectorized approach. More so in phase 2-3 than phase 1 where I didn't have to change it much. ... well it didn't let me paste that much info so I will try another method.

[My PDF of my lab report with code and pictures](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B06IAw3WvXVVMmtiOVd2RFJ2STA/view?usp=sharing)
I know that mode(mode(FI)) is incorrect but I still am curious how phase 2 gets a different hue than phase 3. I think phase 2 is right, and I compared pixel by pixel at one time to verify phase two is same as phase 3, but the mode(FI(:)) should be right. Let me know if you see any problems. I understood most of the vectorization except exactly how using the mask as the index works. I know they call it logical index, but I guess just having a 1 means it will use it and a zero means it will not look at that value.

Comment: Wow! So many answers, but it is still a little complicated. I am trying to understand the answers and decide what one is best. I REALLY like @Divakar who showed a speedup graph.

It seems that there isn't a clean cut way to just plug in the for loop parameters directly into the stuff inside the for loop. 

It has also come to my attention, though it is not the focus of this question, that mode(mode(FI)) may not be the correct way to find the most common color since it does column wise, and then finds the mode of the resulting mode. Depending on the proportion of colors it may not be correct.

Comment: @KalenBrown You are right that there isn't a clear-cut vectorization technique here to just plugin the loop parameters and have a vectorized solution out of it. If you had a single loop instead of the this two nested loops situation, you could have gotten a more direct plug-n-play vectorized solution using logical indexing. But yes, vectorization can't be generalized in most cases and need to dealt with as case-per-case basis. Good luck with the vectorizing explorations!

Comment: Good to see the vectorized codes ending up in that linked lab report!! Wouldn't it be fair to link this Stackoverflow question and/ or answer (vectorized codes from which are incorporated into the pdf) into the pdf's references?

Comment: @Divakar In the references section (which is not at the bottom) I do. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27407712/3988126

Comment: Sweet! I see that now, my apologies as I missed that on my cursory glance earlier. BTW that looks like a well presented and thorough doc after another look at it, good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two very important tools to vectorization - **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** and **[`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)**. Now, `bsxfun` does work with logical operators, so with just these two functions, you can achieve most of your vectorized code.

### `bsxfun` and `logical indexing` in Image Processing

**How and when to use `logical indexing`?**

*In cases, when working with RGB images and specially when needed to index into two dimensions (as is the case here), it could get tricky as you can't directly use logical indexing there.*

One of the tricks that could be employed in such cases would be to use `reshape`, provided the indexing required for the rest of the dimensions is uniformly structured, which is again satisfied in this problem case.

**How and when to use `bsxfun`?**

`bsxfun` finds an optimal solution in various problems. For the given problem, we can use use it for the many equality comparison checks being made in a vectorized fashion.

This is done by reshaping `CommonRGB` into a size such that there is a singleton dimension that corresponds to the combined dimension of `row` and `col` in the reshaped `FI`. `bsxfun` then takes care of the much needed `"expansion"` for the reshaped `CommonRGB` and performs the equality check with the function handle `@eq` that is in-built into it.

Let's jump to the vectorized code that employs these two functions and techniques discussed earlier -

```
%// Reshape the inputs and save as new variables
FIr = reshape(FI,[],3);
BIr = reshape(BI,[],3);
CommonRGBr = reshape(CommonRGB,[],3);

%// Create 1D equality mask corresponding the equality satisfied across 
%// two dimensions - `row` and `col`
mask = all(bsxfun(@eq,FIr,CommonRGBr),2);
swappedPixels = sum(mask); %// Get the count of "swappings"

%// Perform the "swaps" and then reshape FI back to its original size
FIr(mask,:) = BIr(mask,:);
FI = reshape(FIr,size(FI));
```

---

### Benchmarking

Benchmarking of the proposed vectorization code against the original code is discussed in this section. To start off, we have created the
functions forms of the original and vectorized codes.

(1) Original code -

```
function [FI,swappedPixels] = org_code(FI,BI,CommonRGB)

refRows =size(FI,1);
refCols =size(FI,2);

swappedPixels = 0;
for row=1:refRows
    for col=1:refCols
        if(FI(row,col,:)==CommonRGB)
            FI(row,col,:)=BI(row,col,:);
            swappedPixels = swappedPixels + 1;
        end
    end
end

return;
```

(2) Vectorized code -

```
function [FI,swappedPixels] = vectorized_code(FI,BI,CommonRGB)

FIr = reshape(FI,[],3);
BIr = reshape(BI,[],3);
CommonRGBr = reshape(CommonRGB,[],3);

mask = all(bsxfun(@eq,FIr,CommonRGBr),2);
swappedPixels = sum(mask);

FIr(mask,:) = BIr(mask,:);
FI = reshape(FIr,size(FI));

return;
```

(3) Finally here's the benchmarking code that also plots the speedups -

```
N_arr = [100 200 500 1000 2000 4000]; %// datasize array
timeall = zeros(2,numel(N_arr));
for iter = 1:numel(N_arr)
    N = N_arr(iter);
    FI = uint8(randi(255,N,N,3));
    BI = uint8(randi(255,N,N,3));
    
    CommonRGB = mode(mode(FI));
    BI = imresize(BI, [size(FI,1) size(FI,2)]); 
    
    f = @() org_code(FI,BI,CommonRGB);
    timeall(1,iter) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() vectorized_code(FI,BI,CommonRGB);
    timeall(2,iter) = timeit(f);
    clear f
end
figure,hold on,grid on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:)./timeall(2,:),'-bo')
legend('Speedup with Vectorized Code over Original one'),
xlabel('Datasize ->'),ylabel('Speedup Factor (x)')
```

The plot result obtained on my system looked like this -

[image]

### Conclusions

This suggests a whopping close to `170x` speedup with the proposed vectorized solution! Hoping this would somewhat lure you into the business of vectorization and `bsxfun` in particular.

---

### System Configuration

```
MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Operating System: Windows 7
RAM: 3GB
CPU Model: Intel® Pentium® Processor E5400 (2M Cache, 2.70 GHz)
```

Answer (score 2):

You correctly speculated that logical indexing was the way to go. You can select pixels that satisfy a condition in an array and use the result for indexing:

In the case `FI` and `BI` where grayscale images:

```
FI(FI==value)=BI(FI==value);
```

---

**What is happening here:** `FI==value` generates a binary matrix the size of `FI` with 1 (true) at positions where the condition is met and 0 (false) everywhere else. This binary matrix can then be used to access the corresponding elements in `FI` or any other matrix of the same size. Here the elements of `FI` that satisfy the condition are swapped with the ones of `BI` that are at the same positions.

---

The same approach can be used for RGB images, providing you create a 3D array replicating the binary mask along the 3rd dimension, for example using `repmat`.

```
Mask=(FI(:,:,1)==CommonRGB(1,1,1)).*(FI(:,:,2)==CommonRGB(1,1,2)).*(FI(:,:,3)==CommonRGB(1,1,3));
MaskRGB=repmat(Mask, 1, 1, 3);

FI(MaskRGB)=BI(MaskRBG);
```

Note the `.*` are pixelwise multiplications, it's identical to a logical AND. [See also this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/#33f0748f-5b6e-4605-9d0d-a86827bdb8a3). So the first line creates a binary mask where the condition is met in all 3 layers of the RGB image.

If you need the number of swapped pixels, use:

```
swappedPixels = nnz(Mask);
```

Comment: `nnz(X)` should be faster than `numel(find(X))`

Comment: @SchighSchagh thanks for the comment and pointing me out this useful function. Edited accordingly.

Comment: `FI(FI==value)=BI(FI==value);` is very interesting to me. I still have trouble following how the indexing works but if Fi and BI are 2d matrices then I think I could see that it compares FI(1,1) with BI(1,1). It is very interesting how Matlab can have such power in such small syntax! I can see how it gets more confusing with 3D. I now understand the .* and ./ as element wise operations. I will have to walk through your logic more. I will read more on repmat and look into what you have done since `FI(MaskRGB)=BI(MaskRBG);` isn't quite clear to me. 

See my edits to the original question.

Comment: Oh, so .* is like & (not && because it wouldn't know how to short circuit). That makes sense to me because FI(:,:,1)==CommonRGB(1,1,1) would return a 1 or zero as a temp matrix for every place that the first channel matches. After running the == operation on all of the three channels then we would perform the final and operation across all three by multiplying the three temp logical matrices to each other. This satisfies my logic above meaning that the r and g and b channel must match the common rgb. We then store it in a mask matrix which would have the same size as FI. Very nice!

Comment: @KalenBrown you're doing a great job figuring out all these things by yourself. I agree that I like compact code, that is not always the easiest to understand for people who read it :-) Here `repmat`replicates the binary mask along the 3rd dimension to match the 3 layers of the RGB image.

Comment: @KalenBrown I added a bit of additional explanations, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood here is a way you could do it.

Instead of an if-statement you could use [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)  to locate the pixels in each channel of FI that are similar to the most common value for that particular channel (hence the 3rd dimension of commonRGB). Once you have the rows and columns of those pixels, its easy and fast to use logical indexing to swap the pixels from BI to FI. Note that I used test images that ship with Matlab, so the output might not be representative of anything but I think it does what you want. If not please let me know!

Here is the commented code:

```
clear
clc
close all

FI1 = imread('peppers.png');
BI = imread('pears.png');

FI = FI1; %// Only used to display original image

[refRows,refCols,refChan] = size(FI); %// 1-liner for assignments.

CommonRGB = squeeze(mode(mode(FI)));

BI = imresize(BI, [refRows refCols]);

swappedPixels = zeros(1,3); %// We will use it differently than in your code.

%// Loop through each channel and use find to locate pixels in FI that are
%// similar to commonRGB
for CheckChannel = 1:refChan

    [row,col] = find(FI(:,:,CheckChannel) == CommonRGB(CheckChannel));

    FI(row,col,CheckChannel) = BI(row,col,CheckChannel); %// Index pixel value from BI into FI.

    swappedPixels(CheckChannel) = numel(row); %// Calculate the number of elements in the vector, i.e. number of swapped pixels.
end

 swappedPixels %// To see the number of swapped pixels

%// Display results.
figure;

subplot(1,3,1)
imshow(FI1);
title('Original foreground image','FontSize',16);

subplot(1,3,2)
imshow(BI);
title('Original background image','FontSize',16);

subplot(1,3,3)
imshow(FI);
title('Modified foreground','FontSize',16);
```

the array `swappedPixels` looks like this:

```
swappedPixels =

       11175        4508       10753
```

where each number corresponds to one of the 3 dimensions of the images.

The output images look like the following:

[image]

Comment: I am new here so work with me. Thanks so much for attempting to answer my question. 

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think what the logic of your code does is first runs through one color channel like red, and finds all pixels that match the common red and swaps them. While the logic I used in the original question is not the key to the question, I just wanted to point out that I am actually only swapping a pixel if the R and G and B values of the pixel match exactly with the common R and G and B values. 

I think I see how you are vectorizing with row col as "index".

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem this way.

```
  refRows =size(fi,1);
  refCols =size(fi,2);
  CommonRGB = mode(mode(FI));
  % finding where the 3 channels are equals
  [indicesX indicesY ] = find(fi(:,:,1)==CommonRGB(1) & 
                              fi(:,:,2)== CommonRGB(2) & 
                              fi(:,:,3)== CommonRGB(3))


  for c=1:3
       %find the linear index for 3 channels and replace
       idx = sub2ind([refRows ,refCols ,3], indicesX, indicesY,[c c]')
       fi(idx ) = bi(idx );
  end

  %counting swapped pixels
  swappedPixels = length(indicesX);
```